# Connection to http://192.16.154.10 is refused on LockScreen

Tags: android, http-post

I have two activities A-->B(A calls B). For activity B I have manifest entry `noHistory=true` which means the history will not be retained. On activity B I'm making a server call using HTTPPost method. Part of my code is:

```
1. BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
2. String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

Everything in normal scenario is working fine. But when after coming to activity B and successful server call if I will lock the device, then after unlocking that activity A will be launched(Since activity B has `nohistory=true`). Now if I'm calling activity B from A, the app is crashing. The exception I'm able to log is `Connection to http://192.16.154.10 is refused`, in the 2nd line.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Android docs

`android:noHistory`

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack
>   and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away
>   from it and it's no longer visible on screen

you cant able to make a call from B to A, its removed from the stack i guess?

but the error is `Connection to http://192.16.154.10 is refused` not because of `android:noHistory`.

Could you explain  more about your problem?

Comment: But if I'm making `android:noHistory=false`, everything is working fine, coz after unlocking the same activity will be launched that was there at the time of locking.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. This should be a comment not answer